# GetElementByName does not give same result as GetElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have code where half textbox have constant value and other half i can type my text. It all works fine with `GetElementById` but i want change it to `getElementByName`. Have tried several options to make getElementByName work, like `getElementByName ("name")[0].value`, `getElementByName ("name").item(0).value`, but still nothing.

```
var inputA = new halfEditable_INPUT(document.getElementByName ("name").item(0).value);
```

Here is code: https://jsfiddle.net/pact1Lc9/

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementByName`.

```
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
//               --^--
```

Comment: I have tried document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value; also, still my function isn't working.